# Azure AD connect pass thru or AADDS trusts

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I’m looking at getting some servers migrated to azure and I’m stuck at the first hurdle, whether to set up Iaas servers as domain controllers and use Azure AD connect and enable pass thru authentication or to set up Azure AD Domain services and create a one way trust back to on premise and set it up as a resource domain .

The environment at the moment has a tiered architecture, with all key resources sitting in a tier 0 network on premise.

I think what I’d like to know is what does AD use to send the traffic on a trust relationship, I think AD connect uses port 443 and are there any benefits for using AADDS rather than Iaas VMS with ad connect?

Thanks in advance and hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, network connectivity / traffic, here is the traffic map that is necessary for active directory services forest trust, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/179442/how-to-configure-a-firewall-for-domains-and-trusts
the RPC requires a lot of ports, and you cannot restrict it to specific ports.

As for your second question, using AAD DS the benefits is mainly that it's a managed service, you don't have to patch or manage any of domain controller infrastructure like you would a DC VM. you also don't need to manage the aadconnect configuration. But in return, with AADDS, you give up a bit of flexibility. Such as, you are not a domain/forest/enterprise admin. as this is all managed by Microsoft. the other thing you give up with aadds is schema extensions. 
here is a doc on comparing between aadds and adds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/compare-identity-solutions#azure-ad-ds-and-self-managed-ad-ds

Hopefully this helps you on your journey to decide which architecture suits you better.

Comment: thanks for that comprehensive answer. Just wondered if ADVonnect is less secure than a trust relationship?

Comment: If aadConnect is on prem or on the same network as your ad servers, the only ports used is 80/443. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-ports  . All it really does is sync AD data with azure ad, sending it attributes and password hashes (optional) , and passthrough auth requests (again optional). In either scenario, There really isn't much risk. As always with more pieces of software, there is inherently slightly more risk, eg aad connect + passthrough agent if used. I wouldn't worry about security of the two too much, just normal due diligence.